# What is an efficient way to perform calculations which depend on selecting various columns which are indexed by another column

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing

I am trying to subtract one column from another column, but the column changes based on the row. This sounds confusing but an example below makes more sense:
If I have the below dataframe (df)
    a  b  c  d
    2  56 14 16
    3  89 17 13
    2  47 14 19

I want to calculate e, where e is equal to column b - the column indexed by a.
I did this using a for loop for each row but it is very slow:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df$e <- df$b[i] - df[i, (as.integer(df$a[i]))]
}

df

a  b  c  d  e
2  56 14 16 42
3  89 17 13 76
2  47 14 19 33
```

Comment: Thanks! corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use row/column indexing to vectorize this

```
df$e <- df$b - df[-1][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$a)]
df$e
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(2L, 3L, 2L), b = c(56L, 89L, 47L), c = c(14L, 
17L, 14L), d = c(16L, 13L, 19L)), class = "data.frame", 
   row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's any more efficient but if you're interested a `dplyr` + `purrr` solution...

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- structure(list(a = c(2L, 3L, 2L), 
                     b = c(56L, 89L, 47L), 
                     c = c(14L, 17L, 14L), 
                     d = c(16L, 13L, 19L)), 
                class = "data.frame", 
                row.names = c(NA, -3L))


df %>% 
  mutate(e = b - imap_dbl(names(.)[a + 1], ~ pluck(df, .x, .y)))
#>   a  b  c  d  e
#> 1 2 56 14 16 42
#> 2 3 89 17 13 76
#> 3 2 47 14 19 33
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>